# Searching for the title/author of a science fiction book about the invention of a "skyhook', a reactionless drive

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the title and author of a Science Fiction book about the development of a reactionless thruster or drive system. It probably would be considered near-future, hard-SF. The story is told from the viewpoint of the protagonist, who is an astronomer or astrophysicist but who does not have a doctorate in the field. He is a private pilot who owns a small plane whose tail number ends in 22T - "Two To Tango". He was hired by the small company who was developing the thruster system. They referred to the thruster as a "Skyhook". Near the end of the book they proved to the world that the thruster worked by installing in the small plane and using it to fly the plane up the altitude where commercial airliners normally flew.

I seem to recall, but can't be certain of this, that the author was a scientist who wrote fiction on the side.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice question; do you recall when you would have read it?

Comment: I would have read this book sometime in the early to mid-1980's, say something like 1981 to 1985.

Comment: The concept of "skyhook" launch systems was introuced by Hans Moravec in 1978, who attributed the idea to John McCarthy. So it makes sense that hard SF works would start featuring them soon after.  The core concept of these systems was that a satellite with two counter-balancing cables could "roll" along its orbit, with one cable reaching close enough to the earth's surface that a high-flying plane or non-orbital rocket could reach it and "hook" a ride the rest of the way up.   Maybe your story was a fictionalization of a proof-of-concept for that?

Comment: @Ethan There was a fictionalized essay called "[High Wire Act](https://frc.ri.cmu.edu/~hpm/project.archive/general.articles/1981/high.wire/high.wire.html)" about this by Moravec and Robert L. Forward in _Omni_ in 1981, but this doesn't have the plane OP describes or indeed any characters.

Comment: From the comments I see posted so far, I may have mislead you by using the term "Skyhook", even though that is the term used for the device in the novel. In this novel, the term was used as a name for a reactionless drive, not to as a name for a "Beanstalk" or elevator to LEO. A reactionless drive is a device that produces thrust without ejecting any type of reaction mass.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is probably [*Star Driver*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9464) by Lee Correy, a pseudonym used by [G. Harry Stine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._Harry_Stine) - a rocket builder and technology writer.

It was first published in 1980, and concerns a pilot-astronomer called Mike Call who discovers that a top-secret lab has discovered a reactionless drive called a "sky hook". The [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/549128) summary is very skimpy, but I seem to recall that he fitted the drive to his Piper Cherokes, took it up to an altitude where commercial airliners fly, and then used the skyhook to remain there - the airliner pilots reported seeing a light aircraft floating with its engine switched off. This is the event portrayed on the cover of the book, that was jogged in my memory by this question.

[image: Cover of "Star Driver" showing a commercial airliner passing a stationary Piper Cherokee]

Comment: You could also note Mike isn't flying VFR rules. The windscreen is frosted over. There was also a Convair 260 with the drive that was owned by the company he worked before the board pulled the plug on the project. He installed the drive in his own Piper to get it noticed and force reconsideration.

Comment: the FAA would be all over this, the piper is not really obeying the vertical separation either...

Comment: I think "Cherokes" is a typo.  Did you mean "Cherokee"?